# Proper capitalization for surname like McDonald

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am using the code below to capitalize a string properly. I would like to know if there is a better way to code the surname portion, as the way it stands now can become very bloated depending on how many surnames I plan on adding.

This is a follow up to: [Capitalize string except for conjunction words](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49859/capitalize-string-except-for-conjunction-words)

```
Dim conjunctions
Dim suffixes
Dim surnames
Set conjunctions = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
Set suffixes = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
Set surnames = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")

conjunctions.Add("a")
conjunctions.Add("an")
conjunctions.Add("and")
conjunctions.Add("as")
conjunctions.Add("at")
' etc....

suffixes.Add("ii")
suffixes.Add("iii")
suffixes.Add("iv")
suffixes.Add("vi")
suffixes.Add("vii")
suffixes.Add("viii")
suffixes.Add("ix")

surnames.Add("mcdonald")

for each item in xTextSplit
    xWord = item
    if conjunctions.contains(lcase(item)) then
        xWord = lcase(item)
    elseif suffixes.contains(lcase(item)) then
        xWord = ucase(item)
    elseif surnames.contains(lcase(item)) then
        xWord = "Mc" & UCase(Mid(item, 3, 1)) & Mid(item, 4)
    end if
    xCompleteWord = xCompleteWord & " " & xWord
next

queryForHeading = xCompleteWord
queryForHeading = Mid(queryForHeading, 2)
queryForHeading = UCase(Mid(queryForHeading, 1, 1)) & Mid(queryForHeading, 2)
```

Comment: this is a really good question.  what if you have something like `O'`neill or other prefixes as well?

Comment: this really depends on where you are getting the information and what you are going to be doing with the information.  I would probably try writing the code out and seeing what you can come up with that will work for a majority of test cases.

Comment: How are you going to deal with a surname of "van den Platz"? "de Wolfe"? "vanCamp"?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of situations to account for. I can only hope I code for most of them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to create a list of the last names it will get very big, but you would have a list of the names so you could instead

```
surnames.Add("McDonald")
```

And then

```
else
    foreach name in surnames
        if lcase(item) = lcase(name) then
            xWord = name
        end if
    next
end if
```

But, this would get rather long as you add the names in, which is a big downfall when talking about maintenance especially on a VBScript.

Comment: This is definitely something to build on. How come when I try something like O'Neil, it won't keep the capitalization on the N?

Comment: if you have it stored in your ArrayList like `O'Neil` it will work, but if you have it stored `O'neil` than that is what will be returned